# add dynamically data-role pages

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want add dynamically data-role pages in my phonegap application. I thought that I can do this with something like this but isn't working

```
jQuery(function()
{     
    var theList = jQuery('#results');      
    for(i=0; i<mytool_array.length; i++)     
    {           
        content = '<div data-role="page" id="page'+i+'"><div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false"></div><div data-role="content"><p>page=+'+i+'</p></div></div>'; 
        theList.append(content);    
    }   
})

Im my HTML:
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: what is the error?  Also you might want to use the page() after your for loop like this: theList.page();

Comment: I added  theList.page() but it will not add the pages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can predict the problems are:

1. you shouldn't put pages in a div. they should be in body
2. your function starts at DOMready, so it is after (or partially during) jquery mobile makes its formatting
3. rethink your idea. putting basic html structure in body and filling them later should work better
4. Consider making it a `list` or a set of `collapsibles` instead of pages.

This said, your current code should look like this:

```
jQuery(function($)
{     
    var b = $('body');      
    for(i=0; i<mytool_array.length; i++)     
    {           
        $('<div data-role="page" id="page'+i+'"><div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false"></div><div data-role="content"><p>page=+'+i+'</p></div></div>') //newline added for readability. it shouldn't be here
        .appendTo(b).page();    //newline added for readability
    }   
});
```

Comment: Maybe that is the problem that the function starts after the jquery mobile formatting, becauce I can't get this working. Further in the code I call the page with <li><a href="page"><h1>Page</h1></a></li>.

Comment: no, you don't 'call the page' with a html link. it's about calling a method in javascript that is called `.page()`. You didn't even take the time to scroll the code field of my answer? :D

Comment: I don't understand you (I'm a beginner). I create several dynamic links in my HTML code created by javascript. Now I want link that pages with dynamic data role pages.

Comment: To link to a page you generated already you need to give it an id like `id="page1"` attribute and then put `href="#page1"` in the link. Is that it?

Comment: Exactly, and now I want link that hrefs to the pages that are created with the jquery function loop.

Comment: So why don't you do what I wrote here all about? Please read the whole thing again.

Comment: Yes I try to use your code, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: How does it not work and what do you expect it to do? Can you publish any demo?